# pandas Groupby MonthStart with two business days offset

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a `DataFrame` that is indexed by date and has daily data.

As described I wish to group and aggregate this data by calendar month start minus 2 business days. My idea is to use `groupby` and `MonthBegin` with a 2 days `BDay` offset to this.

When I try run the code

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.tseries.offsets as of
days = of.MonthBegin() - of.BDay(2)
g = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq=days, level='Date')).sum()
```

I get an error

> TypeError: Argument 'other' has incorrect type (expected
>   datetime.datetime, got BusinessDay)

Perhaps I need to use the `rollback` method on `MonthBegin` but when I try

```
days = of.MonthBegin()
days.rollback(of.BDay(2))
g_df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq=days, level='Date')).sum()
```

> TypeError: Cannot convert input [<2 * BusinessDays>] of type  to Timestamp

Does anyone have any ideas how to correctly use the `offsets` to groupby `MonthBegin - 2BDay` ?

Comment: Have you tried this `pd.offsets.MonthBegin().rollback(pd.Timestamp('2014-01-02'))`

Comment: But what does that date 2014/01/02 mean?

Comment: If you need to offset it back to be `2014-01-01`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to tell, what you want to achieve without any data of yours, but here is how you could do it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"dates": ["2018-01-02", "2018-01-03", "2018-02-02", "2018-01-04"],
                "vals": [10, 20, 10, 5]})

df.groupby((pd.to_datetime(df.dates) - of.MonthBegin() - of.BDay(2)).dt.month).vals.sum()
```

Output:

```
dates
1    10
12   35
Name: vals, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I've made an amend to the question. Essentially I have daily data which I wish to group by `MonthBegin() - BDay(2)`